# Linear Algebra from Artin

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

This is question M.5 from Chapter 4 of Artin's Algebra:

M.5.b. Let $\phi: F^n \to F^m$ be left multiplication by an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ (where $F $ is a field). Prove that the following are equivalent:

(i) $A$ has a left inverse, a matrix $B$ such that $BA=1_{F^n}$.

(ii) $\phi$ is injective.

(iii) The rank of $A$ is $n$.

My attempt: The matrix $A $ represents the linear map $\phi $ with respect to the standard bases of $F^n $ and $F^m $.

(i) $\leftrightarrow$ (ii): A function $\phi: F^n \to F^m$ is injective if and only if there is a function $\psi$ such that $\psi \phi=1_{F^n}$; that is, $\phi$ is injective if and only if $\phi$ has a left inverse. Let $B$ be the matrix of $\psi$ with respect to the chosen basis for $F^n$. Then $\psi \phi=1_{F^n}$ is equivalent to a matrix $B$ such that $BA=1_{F^n}$.

(ii) $\leftrightarrow$ (iii): We know that if $T: V \to W$ is a linear transformation, then
$$
\dim \ker T + \dim \text{im }T = \dim V
$$
where $\dim \text{im} T = \text{rank} T$. For our case, we have
$$
\dim \ker \phi + \text{rank }\phi= n
$$
If $\phi$ is injective, then $\dim \ker \phi=0$ so that $\text{rank}\phi =n$. If $\text{rank}\phi =n$, then it is clear that $\dim \ker \phi=0$ so that $\phi$ is injective.

Is this really all there is to it? There just is usually so much more to the 'Miscellaneous Problems' to Artin!

Comment: That's really all there is to it

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks! Feel free to post this comment as a solution and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 3):

You have to be a bit careful in your first equivalence: You say that *there is a function $\psi$*, and then later take the matrix of $\psi$ with respect to the bases. The problem here is that you did not require $\psi$ to be linear, and left inverses of linear maps do not necessarily have to linear themselves. So in your current proof it does not make sense to take the matrix of $\psi$, as this is only possible for linear maps.

So you either need to refer to some results you already know about the existence of linear left inverses, or construct one yourself.

A hint for doing it yourself: The standard basis $(e_1, \dotsc, e_n)$ of $K^n$ is mapped to a linearly independent familiy $(\phi(e_1), \dotsc, \phi(e_n))$ in $K^m$ by the injectivity of $\phi$. This can be extended to a basis $(\phi(e_1), \dotsc, \phi(e_n),f_{n+1},\dotsc,f_m)$ of $K^m$. Now try the define a linear left inverse $\psi \colon K^m \to K^n$ by specifying what it does on the vectors of this basis.